# Which indexes should I use for inline strings?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I storing some strings like: Barcelona, Real Madrid, Athletico. My program need to search full match of this,

For example:

```
Barcelona    -> true
Real Madrid  -> true
Real M       -> false
Athletic     -> false
```

I think to store it inline in text/varchar field, like (just rude example):

`|Barcelona|Real Madrid|Athletico|` and then just make `LIKE %|Real Madrid|%`

I don't want to use any heavy things like trigram, just inline string, but which indexing system should I use?

Thx

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to search for the occurrence of one of these strings at a time or for several at once? If the latter: AND or OR?

Comment: Only one per select:
    SELECT * FROM db WHERE column LIKE '%|Real Madrid|%' LIMIT 1

Comment: Do **not** store multiple delimited values in a single column. Read up on database normalization. If you really think you have to de-normalize your data model and violate first normal form, then at least use an array.

Comment: Thx for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use [Arrays type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/arrays.html) for store your data and use `ANY` keyword in `WHERE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    teams   text[]
);

INSERT INTO games (teams) 
VALUES ({'Real Madrid','Maccabi Haifa', 'Manchester United'})

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'Real Madrid'= ANY (teams);
```

For improve performance [GIN Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/gin.html) can be used with Array field:

```
    CREATE INDEX ON games USING gin(teams);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I thought about it from the very beginning. But how it works with doctrine? doctrine have it's own arrays...

Comment: And does normalization better practice than arrays? How to make choice?

Comment: @MegaBomber, unfortunately I'm to familiar with doctrine and can't help you. In common case the normalization is better, but it may be overhead in you private case. The choice should be based on global project vision, so I can not advice you without deep knowledge about your project.

Comment: No, I just globally wanna know in which cases I need rather normalization and when arrays is better.

Comment: Without know the exact detail for every use you want for this data then normalization is the way to go. Disclaimer: I tend to think arrays are bad design is almost every case. Too restrictive unless I want all the elements all time.